# PHPUNIT how to get the current class into another file

Tags: phpunit

I have a common class A called by anothers php files.
And I want to get the name of current class into the class A.

Here **class A** :

```
class A extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

............................

public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{

try {
**Here the function to get the class**  ??????
    self::$selenium = new ObjetConnexion();
    self::$tab_castest= array();
    self::$nbjeu = -1;
 } catch (Testing_Selenium_Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}

}
```

**Class B** :
    class BTest extends A
    {

```
protected function setUp()
{
    ...

}
public function testConnexion()
{  
......
}
}
```

And the content of the phpunit.xml :

```
  <file>Nouveaux_services/BTest.php</file>
  <file>Nouveaux_services/CTest.php</file>
  <file>Nouveaux_services/DTest.php</file>

</testsuite>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You mean http://php.net/get_class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the called class with `get_called_class()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php